# Angular: Sanitizing an img tag within sanitized HTML

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that uses an HTML snippet received by a trusted external source. I am using Angular's DomSanitizer and the bypassSecurityTrustHtml method in particular to process the variable containing the snippet before binding it to my template using innerHTML.

The issue I have though is that this snippet contains an img tag with the src attribute being an external domain/url. So essentially I need to sanitize that as well by using something like bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl.

I've tried nesting the bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl (by casting it to a string) inside the bypassSecurityTrustHtml method, but this doesn't seem right and it also doesn't work.

Anyone out there come across this type of issue before?

Here's a quick Stackblitz demonstrating what i'm trying to achieve:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqvhbc

Comment: add live demo, and reproduce this state, it helps in debug

Comment: Here's a Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqvhbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `img` tag you were providing was not proper.

```
<img src="https://www.google.com.au/logos/doodles/2018/doodle-snow-games-day-7-5009413877268480.2-s.png" >
```

Initially it was just `<img="URL">`

Here is the [Updated stackblitz URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1fxtnw?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Hey, sorry that was a typo on my end. However you did help me get to the root cause and fix my problem which wasn't actually due to the sanitization not working, that works fine - I had to decode some html entities before passing the html to the template, so thank you!  The reason I thought the image was the issue was because the html tags for the image were html encoded, once I fixed that there was no issue. :-/